# Delphi 7, TTable, Csv file fields

Tags: delphi, file, csv

HI,
My Question may be a simple one for you.

I have to import a csv file to my delphi application. This file contains 3 columns and I want to match the columns to one of Dataset( TQuery connected to a Firebird table) and show on a grid.

My Question is, is it possible to use the Csv file as a table, who can access by a SQL query and join to a Db table ?

I have tried with TTable with TableType property as ttASCII. It loads the file.However this loads the contents to a single fields,
ie, Fields[0].asstring gives '11,12,abc.txt'
I want this on different fields
ie, 
Fields[0].asstring = '11'
Fields[1].asstring = '12'
Fields[3].asstring = 'abc.txt'

Hope you understand my requirement. Kindly take a look and let me know your thoughts

Thanks and Regards,

Vijesh V.Nair

System Analyst

Answer (score 1):

Vijesh , you have to create a schema definition file to access a txt file from a `TTable` component, the name of the schema file must the same of the text file but with the `SCH` extension.
in this link you can found more information about the format of the schema file  [`Using The ASCII Driver With Comma-delimited Files`](http://unicornix.spb.ru/docs/prog/delphi/delphi_faq/del_tis/TI2844.html), also you can check the `BDE32.HLP` file.

Comment: Hi RRUZ,Thanks for the comment. I have tried I make a sch file, contents as follows,   

[SEEVEE_RESULTS]
Filetype=VARYING
Delimiter="
Separator=,
CharSet=ascii
Field1=id,NUMBER,3,00,00
Field2=hits,NUMBER,3,00,00
Field3=File,Char,3,00,00

But still showing same. Kidly take a look and let me know.

Comment: Hi,I have solved. [SEEVEE_RESULTS]
Filetype=VARYING
Delimiter="
Separator=,
CharSet=ascii
Field1=CONTID,NUMBER,8,00,00
Field1=HITS,NUMBER,8,00,00
Field3=FILEPATH,Char,255,00,00

Comment: Thanks for comments. I have an Issue.I made some Lookup Fields to this TTable.

I want to Sort the Table. When I am Trying to Use AddIndex. I am getting 
"Capability not supported." Messgae
with TblCVResults do
 Begin
     Try
          TableName  :=  'C:\123.txt';
          Active     :=  True;
          AddIndex('ndxHits','HITS',[]);
          AddIndex('ndxPostCode','LkPostCode',[]);
          IndexDefs.Update;
          DM.TblCVResults.IndexName := 'ndxHits';
        except
          on E: Exception do
            MsgError(E.Message);
        end;
End
Kindly Tell me How?

Comment: You should ask this as a new question, rather than in the comments, then other users can see the solution more clearly. Rgds, Stuart.